# does windows appfabric require Sql Server Express?

Tags: appfabric

I am using the windows platform installer to install AppFabric, it says that SQL Express is required?  Can't i use the SQL Server R2?  I don't really want to install SQL Express.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you absolutely can use full SQL Server with AppFabric. I suspect it's listed as a dependency in the Web PI so it'll install correctly for people who *don't* have SQL Server installed.